# How to set file association which was lost (for an already installed program)?

Tags: windows-10, file-association, r

In my R (Rgui 3.6.1), I lost the file association to .Rdata files after I uninstalled older versions of R (this probably is a bug and shoudln't happen! The association was referring to version 3.6.1 which I didn't uninstall).

So I went to Windows 10 System settings "Choose default app by file type". But here, I cannot choose "R", even though it's installed! :

[image]

That's strange, because Windows 10 itself recognizes R as installed:

[image]

How can I set the file associations again? Is it possible somehow through these Settings? Or do I have to use Regedit? I'd prefer not to... Looking at Regedit, the associations for `.rda` and `.Rdata` are completely empty and I don't know what to put there:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you right-click on .RData, slect *Open with...*,  and *More apps*, scroll to the *bottom*, and *Look for another app on this PC*?

[image: Open With Dlg]

You should be able to browse to the application and select it. Check the box to make it default.

If that doesn't work, uninstall the newer version and reinstall.